# How can a question be "Too Story Based" if there is no story involved?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

This question is currently on hold for being too story based; [What would be a realistic timeline for these prosthetic related events?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/105917/what-would-be-a-realistic-timeline-for-these-prosthetic-related-events)

But, the problem I am having is, there is no story in the question. I am creating a world for a Tabletop rpg. I am not writing a story. There is no story present, there are no characters and there is no plot. I am not even planning on writing a story. I am purely creating a world for other people to create a story in (so to say).

So, how can a question without a story involved, still be closed/put on hold as "Too story based"?
And how to fix that, if there is no story in the first place?

Comment: Your question is now open again. Your editing helped a lot by placing the focus on the specific problem you’re having rather than the general story in which it takes place, and I think it’s reasonably answerable now. It may have simply taken some time for reopen voters to see that you had edited it and review it.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: @Dubukay Thank you.

Comment: Meta effect strikes again!

Comment: @Dubukay Considering the first sentence in the question says this about Table RPG, the whole concept of there being a story involved seems to this little black duck as ridiculous. The original version had a slab of history to prosthetics. Now the question is more focused making it a better story by far. Anyone suggesting the question was story-based was wrong.